# Show that a certain set of sets is a topology

Tags: general-topology

I need to solve this question but I can´t find the unions and intersections of the subsets of $X$.

Let $X$ an infinite set and let $x_0\in X$.

$\tau$ = $\{A \subset X : x_0 \notin A\} \cup \{ A \subseteq X : x_0 \in A,   X\setminus A  
 \text{ is finite}\}$

(a) Show that $\tau$ is topology in $X$.

(b) Find the dense sets in $(X,\tau)$.

Comment: What have you done already ?

Comment: The item (a) is Ok
Now, I don´t find the dense sets.

Answer (score 1):

(For A) Call $\{A\subseteq X\,:\, x_0\in A\}=\Lambda$ and $\{A\subseteq X\,:\, X\setminus A\in\mathcal P_f(X)\wedge x_0\in A\}=\Gamma$.

The key observations here are:

1. $\Gamma$ and $\Lambda$, separately, are closed under unions and binary intersections
2. For the "mixed" unions in $\tau$, notice that $A\in \Gamma$ and $B\supseteq A$ implies $B\in \Gamma$
3. For the "mixed" intersections in $\tau$, notice that $A\in\Lambda$ and $B\subseteq A$ implies $B\in \Lambda$

Comment: What B ? Give me an example.

Comment: Any $B$. Say $ A $ contains everything except $926$ elements and $ B $ is larger than $ A $. Then...

Comment: Why I need of B in 2. ?

Comment: As I said, for unions.

Comment: Ok. Why I find the dense sets?

Comment: I did not address that: I thought your issue was with unions and intersections only. Notice that the closed sets are either the finite ones or the ones which contain $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

B.  For all $x \neq x_0$, $\{x\}$ is open.  Thus if $D$ is dense, it will contain
all the points $\neq x_0$.

Comment: Please learn a bit of LateX/MathJax. There are tutorials on this site.

Answer (score 0):

$\emptyset \in \tau$, because $x_0 \notin \emptyset$.
$X \in \tau$ because $x_0 \in X$ and $X\setminus X = \emptyset$ is finite.

Suppose we have two sets $U,V \in \tau$ for $\tau$ to be closed under finite intersections we only need to show $U \cap V \in \tau$ (the rest is induction).

Some cases: if $x_0 \notin U$ or $x_0 \notin V$ (so one of them is of the first type) then $x_0 \notin U \cap V$ (this set is smaller, so cannot contain $x_0$ either). The only remaining case is that $x_0 \in U, x_0 \in V$ and $X \setminus U$ finite and $X \setminus V$ finite. Then $x_0 \in U \cap$ and $X \setminus (U \cap V) = (X \setminus U) \cup (X\setminus V)$ is also finite. So $U \cap V \in \tau$ in all cases.

Suppose $O_i, i \in I$ are all members of $\tau$, we must show that $O = \cup_{i \in I} O_i$ is in $\tau$ as well.
If one of the sets $O_i$ is of the second type, then $x_0 \in O_i$ (so $x \in O$) and $X \setminus O \subseteq X\setminus O_i$ are both finite. So in that case we are done, and $O$ is also open of the second type.
So assume that all $O_i$ are open of the first type, then for all $i$, $x_0 \notin O_i$, and this implies that $x_0 \notin O$, so $O$ is open of the first type.

A set $D$ is dense iff $\forall O \in \tau: (O \neq \emptyset \rightarrow O \cap D \neq \emptyset)$. If $D$ is dense in $X$: for any $x \neq x_0$, $\{x\}$ is open so the above condition implies $\{x\} \cap D \neq \emptyset$, so $x \in D$.
Hence $D$ is dense then $X\setminus \{x_0\} \subseteq D$. Note that the reverse also holds. So the only dense subsets are $X\setminus\{x_0\}$ and $X$ itself.

Comment: I didn't find a TeX tutorial in the stack.

Comment: @WilliamElliot See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, e.g.